# Magento 2 :Get Customer Zip from Checkout Shipping Step

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, zipcode

I have a custom module with a custom section in Checkout Payment Step.

[image]

I want to display the xip code of the customer in the custom section ( both customer logged in and logged out case).

I have used the below code

```
if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    if ($customer) {
        $billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        if ($billingAddress) {
            return $billingAddress->getPostcode();
        }
    }
} else {
    $postCode = $this->checkoutsession->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
    return $postCode;
}
```

But in the logged out case, not getting the zip code in the payment step. When I refresh the page, it displays.

Please help.

Comment: You can try using javascript functions to set the payment method area zip code. Use the javascript function to get the zip code field value from shipping area html and assign this value to the payment method area, zip code html element.

Comment: @MGento I want to get it in my  config provider

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery Solution**

```
$( "button[data-role='opc-continue']" ).on( "click", function() {

        $(".yourclass").html($("input[name='postcode']").val());
});
```

Comment: I want to get the value in my config provider.